# How to hide menu options for users on Site Settings page?

Tags: site-settings

What is the best way to hide menu options/links on the site settings page?

In particular I want to hide SharePoint Designer Settings from end users so they do not see this option.

There are others I would like to hide also.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Site Collection scope FEATURE, include following:

```
<HideCustomAction
  GroupId = "SiteCollectionAdmin"
  HideActionId = "SharePointDesignerSettings"
  Id = "HideSharePointDesignerSettings"
  Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings">
</HideCustomAction>
```

Beware of Documentation located at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx
Some of the IDs are wrong and NOT all are documented there. For example the one that you are looking is not included in MSDN. About wrong values see: http://sp10tech.blogspot.com/2010/11/wrong-values-for-location-and-groupid.html

I found above setting from: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\SiteSettings\SiteSettings.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Build a custom action that would be a [HideCustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx) and that would hide any element you want.  The list of elements that you can use/hide are presented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx).