# sharepoint 2010: revoke rights to see "users and permissions"

Tags: permissions, security, settings

I have a sharepoint site and i want few users not to see "Users and Permissions" in 'site settings'. It should not disturb anything else.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/how-to-hide-menu-options-for-users-on-site-settings-page).
You can use [HideCustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx), I believe this can solve your problem

**updates

[Create a new permission level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx) and under Site Permissions, uncheck Manage Permissions and Enumerate Permissions. After you have create a new group with the new custom permission, add those users. When any of those users log in, they will not see the User And Permissions group in the Site Settings page as well as the Site Permission link in the Site Actions.

Comment: I want to hide it only for certain users instead of all users. and I want to achieve this without custom code. I was hoping that i could achieve this with altering security permission for those user.

Comment: yes..definitely you can.See my updates